# onEdit varias hojas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Como hago para que la función onEdit pueda trabajar independientemente en diferentes hojas. Verán hice esta script que funciona perfectamente en la hoja activa(Col Y). Tengo 8 hojas(distintos nombres) en los cuales al modificar una columna especifica me estampe la fecha y hora en la celda adyacente, para cada hoja es una columna distinta. Intente hacer varias funciones onedit y no funciona ninguna. GRacias por su apoyo.

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ColY = 25;  // Número de la Columna "Y"

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColY) {
    // Una celda de la Columna Y ha sido editada
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColY+1);
    var timestamp = new Date(); // Obtener la fecha actual
    // Dependiendo del valor de la celda será lo que se hará
    switch (state) {
      case 'Liquidado':
        // Escribir la fecha en la celda contigua
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break;
      case 'En Stock':
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break;
      default:
        // Algo que no se esperaba
        adjacent.setValue("*ERROR*");
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Casualmente hoy encontré tus preguntas hechas aquí y en el foro oficial de Google Drive y los editores de documentos de Google y que has usado el mismo nombre de usuario en ambos sitios. Cuando se hacen publicaciones cruzadas es de buenos modales el hacer mención de ello y mejor aún cuando se incluye un enlace. Al menos en la publicación más reciente debería incluirse un enlace a la publicación original sin embargo y en consideración de que la idea de hacer preguntas en estos sitios es ayudar a otros, lo mejor mejor, sería poner enlaces a las publicaciones cruzadas en todas ellas.

Comment: Creo que la unica respuesta que existe aqui no haya resuelto el problema de amigo, yo le entiendo y tambien entiendo la respuesta, pues a mi me pasa lo mismo pues tengo dos checkbox para diferentes funciones que deben activare con onEdit y esto no funciona sino solo para un caso,...por lo tanto debe existir una forma de diferenciarlos al activar cualquier de los dos diferentes funciones del checkbox.
Esto es similar a lo del amigo

Answer (score 0):

> Adaptación de mi publicación en https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs-es/n_u7ih1wH2U/7vz8Gbs0AAAJ

No me queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr, pero en relación a tener varios onEdit, te comparto lo siguiente:

1. En Google Apps Script / JavaScript un concepto importante es el ámbito. De forma muy general, están el ámbito global y el ámbito del objeto.
2. Todos los archivos en un proyecto de Google Apps Script comparten el mismo ámbito global
3. Por lo anterior y dado que los archivos se cargan uno a uno en un orden que sólo Google sabe, si defines varias funciones con el mismo nombre, sólo entrará en efecto la cargada al último.

No relacionado directamente con la pregunta, pero igual te puede servir para mejorar tu script: es mas eficiente usar event.range en lugar de event.source.getActiveRange() ya que te ahorras una llamada a los servicios de Google Apps Script lo cual es recomendable para minimizar el tiempo de ejecución.